# JQuery custom validation (errorClass, errorElement and errorPlacement)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've been struggling with trying to configure jquery validation all afternoon and was wondering If I could get some help.

I'm using yaml.css as my css framework. The way that yaml works for forms is that the original form looks like this...

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" class="ym-form" action="/ReportingManager/j_spring_security_check" method="post">                               
   <div class="ym-fbox">
      <label for="j_username">Username<sup class="ym-required">*</sup></label>
      <input id="j_username" name="j_username" placeholder="enter a value" class="{required:true}" type="text" value="" maxlength="30"/>
   </div>       
   <input id="loginBtn" type="submit" class="ym-button ym-primary" value="Log in" title="Log in" />                     
</form>
```

After the form is submitted with errors I need to do 2 things....

1-Add the following just below the input field (inside ym-fbox div)...

`<p class="ym-message"> jquery error message here </p>`

2-Change the parent div which encloses my input form element in error to add a class named ym-error..

from...

```
<div class="ym-fbox">
```

to ...

```
<div class="ym-fbox ym-error">
```

I was hesitant to post what I've tried because it does not work but just to show that I have made an attempt this is what I have tried so far...

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("form").validate({
        ...
    errorClass:'ym-error',
    errorElement: 'p',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
            $(element).parents("div").addClass(errorClass); 
        },      
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
            $(element).parents("div").removeClass(errorClass); 
        },
```

It is not good. Can anybody give me some help with roughly how the form validate method  should look please?

thanks

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WZvTx/2/ ... instead of `parents()` use `.closest()`

Comment: your modification to my original worked beautifully with a bit of tweaking. Thank you.

Comment: What does "not good" mean?

Comment: by not good i meant to working as i wanted it to

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others... I solved this with the help of Arun....

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("form").validate({
        onblur: false,
        onchange: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        onsubmit: true,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).removeClass('dirty');
            $('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('button').addClass('disabled');
            form.submit();
        },
        errorClass:'ym-message',
        errorElement: 'p',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
            $(element).closest("div").addClass("ym-error");
        },      
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
            $(element).closest("div").removeClass("ym-error"); 
        },      
        ignore: ".ignore"
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI- [read the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).  `onsubmit: true` is not valid.  Since that's the default state, you'll break this function.   Only use `false` or an overriding  function.  Otherwise, just leave out this option.

Comment: thanks Sparky. Using this code it at least added the classes and showed the error messages that I wanted it to. But I'll have a read of the doco and change the onsubmit. Cheers for that tip